# Unable to change css values in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I've been testing my latest project with Chrome for a few days now. Everything was working as it should. I had no warnings or errors in the console and I was able to tweak CSS attributes on the fly which would take effect in the browser window. All normal behaviour.

Yesterday I updated Chrome to the latest version and for some reason I now get CSS warnings in the console and I'm unable to update CSS on the fly. I read that the two are related, if you have CSS warnings you cannot edit the CSS values. My issue is that there were no warnings before and now there are.

The warnings are all for "invalid CSS property value". I'm wondering if I've changed a setting that no longer ignores invalid CSS.

These are the warnings:

[image]

Anyone experienced the same thing?